# Merging excel files with heterogeneous filenames in R

Tags: r, excel

I'm trying to merge data from multiple subjects, one excel file each, into a single database using a loop in R. Each sheet is identical in structure (column names, number of rows etc), however the filename in each case contains the date and time at which it was created. Each one is obviously different, meaning it's very difficult to make a working loop.

Here's an example of two file paths:

subject 1: "Data/001/001_behavData_12_Sep_1125.csv"

subject 2: "Data/002/002_behavData_14_Sep_1342.csv"

Here is what my loop looks like right now:

```
subjects = c("001","002","003","004","005"...)

for (i in subjects) {
    path = paste0(i, "/", i, "_behavData", ****, ".csv"}
```

**** is the string of 11 characters which is different for each subject. Is there a way to tell R to ignore this section of each filename? Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to list the files is to use `list.files()` with the options to return the full file names and recurse the subdirectories.

```
theList <- list.files("./data",pattern="csv",full.names=TRUE,recursive=TRUE)
theList
```

and the output:

```
 > 
 > theList
 [1] "./data/All Penalties.csv"                      
 [2] "./data/baseballPlayers.csv"                    
 [3] "./data/cameras.csv"                            
 [4] "./data/epa-extreme-precip.csv"      
  ...           
 [17] "./data/ontime/2016-11_T_ONTIME.csv"            
 [18] "./data/ontime/2016-12_T_ONTIMEcsv.csv"         
 [19] "./data/ontime/2017-01_T_ONTIME.csv"  
 ...          
 [43] "./data/week3q1.csv"                            
 >
```

To read the files, we use the list as an argument in `lapply()`. Note that if the files are CSVs, we use `read.csv()` instead of `openxlsx::read.xlsx()` which would be used to read Excel spreadsheets.

```
theSheets <- lapply(theList,function(x) {
    read.csv(x,...) # add options at ellipsis, such as header=TRUE
})
```

Then use `do.call()` with `rbind()` to join to a single data frame.

```
theData <- do.call(rbind, theSheets)
```

A complete example using Pokémon stats data originally collected by [Alberto Barradas on kaggle.com](https://www.kaggle.com/abcsds/pokemon) is:

```
# Example using Pokémon data files retrieved from kaggle.com and
# broken out into 6 csv files, one per generation
# raw data files available at https://github.com/lgreski/pokemonData

thePokemonFiles <- list.files("./pokedata",pattern="gen",
                              full.names=TRUE)
thePokemonFiles
pokemonData <- lapply(thePokemonFiles,function(x) read.csv(x))

combinedData <- do.call(rbind,pokemonData)

# sumarize the data 
summary(combinedData)
```

...and the output.

```
> thePokemonFiles <- list.files("./pokedata",pattern="gen",
+                               full.names=TRUE)
> thePokemonFiles
[1] "./pokedata/gen01.csv" "./pokedata/gen02.csv" "./pokedata/gen03.csv"
[4] "./pokedata/gen04.csv" "./pokedata/gen05.csv" "./pokedata/gen06.csv"
> pokemonData <- lapply(thePokemonFiles,function(x) read.csv(x))
> 
> combinedData <- do.call(rbind,pokemonData)
>
> # sumarize the data 
> summary(combinedData)
     Number                             Name         Type1          Type2    
 Min.   :  1.0   Abra                     :  1   Water  :112           :385  
 1st Qu.:185.5   Aerodactyl               :  1   Normal : 98   Flying  : 97  
 Median :365.0   AerodactylMega Aerodactyl:  1   Grass  : 70   Ground  : 35  
 Mean   :363.1   Alakazam                 :  1   Bug    : 69   Poison  : 34  
 3rd Qu.:539.5   AlakazamMega Alakazam    :  1   Psychic: 56   Psychic : 33  
 Max.   :721.0   Arbok                    :  1   Fire   : 52   Fighting: 26  
                 (Other)                  :793   (Other):342   (Other) :189  
...
```

**UPDATE:** 18Dec2017 - To associate an ID with each data file, one can parse the file names as follows.

```
pokemonData <- lapply(thePokemonFiles,function(x) {
     data <- read.csv(x)
     tokens <- unlist(strsplit(x,"/"))
     data$source <- substr(tokens[3],4,5)
     data
     })

combinedData <- do.call(rbind,pokemonData)
head(combinedData)
```

...and the output.

```
> pokemonData <- lapply(thePokemonFiles,function(x) {
+      data <- read.csv(x)
+      tokens <- unlist(strsplit(x,"/"))
+      data$source <- substr(tokens[3],4,5)
+      data
+      })
> 
> combinedData <- do.call(rbind,pokemonData)
> head(combinedData)
  Number                  Name Type1  Type2 Total HP Attack Defense SpecialAtk SpecialDef Speed Generation Legendary source
1      1             Bulbasaur Grass Poison   318 45     49      49         65         65    45          1     False     01
2      2               Ivysaur Grass Poison   405 60     62      63         80         80    60          1     False     01
3      3              Venusaur Grass Poison   525 80     82      83        100        100    80          1     False     01
4      3 VenusaurMega Venusaur Grass Poison   625 80    100     123        122        120    80          1     False     01
5      4            Charmander  Fire          309 39     52      43         60         50    65          1     False     01
6      5            Charmeleon  Fire          405 58     64      58         80         65    80          1     False     01
>
```

Comment: Len, thanks so much - this worked a treat! I have one final question - is there a way to add a unique identifier to each row, according to which file it came from? Each file in my directory came from an individual subject - therefore I would like to add a "subject" column to the final data frame.

Comment: If it helps, each file contributed exactly 60 rows to the data frame, so I suppose one way is to assign a different value every 60th row..?

Comment: @Lyam - I will update the post to illustrate how to extract data from the file names and add it as a column in each data set. Also, if the answer solved your problem, please accept it.

Comment: I've accepted the answer. Thanks for the additional help. I tried parsing up the file name as you suggested. When I use do.call it gives me the following error: Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : numbers of columns of arguments do not match. I don't see how adding an ID to each row could cause this...?

Comment: @Lyam - Please post the code that you're using in the `lapply()` function so we can diagnose the error.

Comment: `sheetsA = lapply(theList,function(x) {
  data = read.xlsx(x)
  sheet = 4
  rows = 1:61
  tokens = unlist(strsplit(x,"/"))
  data$source = substr(tokens[3],4,5)
  data
})`

Comment: @Lyam - Assuming that you are using the `openxlsx` package, the `read.xlsx()` line should probably be `read.xlsx(x,sheet=4,rows=1:61)` . My guess is that the current code is reading a different worksheet, and the worksheet being read has different numbers of columns across the list of files you're reading.  Also note that you'll need to change the tokens substring from my example to match the pattern in the actual file names you're reading.

Comment: Len, you were correct. I changed the code as you suggested and it resolved the problem. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list.files`which allow to extract all the files with the same format for example with .csv, then you can use for example `map_df` with the `read_csv` function:

```
list.files(getwd(), pattern = "*.csv")%>% 
map_df(read_csv())
```

NOTE: get_wd() must be the directory of your files, I use this because normally the files are in your working directory.

Hope that helps!